# What is the advantage of a 64-bit browser on Mac?

Tags: macos, 64-bit, browser

With the advent of Mac OS X Snow Leopard, Apple's first 64-bit consumer OS, all the major web browsers (Safari, Firefox, and Chrome) have become 64-bit. What is the advantage of a 64-bit browser over a 32-bit one on Mac? Even though Windows also has 64-bit versions of their OS, most Windows users are still running browsers in 32-bit mode. I understand the need for 64-bit computing in data intensive programs like Winrar, which need bitwise manipulation, but I don't see why a browser would need 64 bits per integer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The probably most important aspect is:

**64-bit browser use 64-bit plugins while 32-bit browsers use 32-bit plugins.**

Keeping this in mind, a 64-bit browser is both good and bad:

- Usually, 64-bit plugins are harder to find as their 32-bit counterparts.
- Plugins like the Java Runtime Environment let your browser perform CPU intensive and/or memory hungry tasks. The 64-bit version of JRE has access to all cores, making some tasks magnitudes faster.

Comment: +1. And those tasks that are magnitudes faster may be invisible to all but the heaviest users.

Comment: Good observation .... but I can't recall the last time I saw a Java widget running on a website :D They seem to have gone out of style.

Comment: Take the applet [Factorization using the Elliptic Curve Method](http://alpertron.com.ar/ECM.HTM) for example. Integer factorization is very CPU intensive and highly parallelizable .

Comment: You must keep in mind that even with all of the optimizations that can be taken advantage of by using a 64-bit browser, (i.e. all cores in java) the website itself (and components contained within) must also be written specifically to take advantage of them.  Of which the vast majority are not.

Comment: @TheCompWiz: You are right about the *components contained within* (but you cannot write a *website* for 32-bit or 64-bit CPUs) and I agree that most users won't benefit from a 64-bit JRE, but it can save quite some time in the right occasions.

Comment: @Dennis I am not sure if the javascript engine is completely free from 64-bit enhancements...

Comment: @TheCompWiz : Why can't 32-bit programs can't use all cores? (Unless the number of cores exceeds the max integer value - which will not happen for another 100 years)

Comment: @TheCompWiz: OK, you got me there. But JavaScript is not parallelizable and it's generally a bad idea to make it do CPU intensive tasks...

Comment: @jojo 32-bit programs most certainly can...  The 32-bit version of Java on the other hand won't run in more than 1 thread... so in a web-browser... it's stuck running on a single-core.  (as are many other components)

Comment: @TheCompWiz : really? I recall back in college, I was still on 32-bit Windows XP and I wrote a multi-threaded ray tracer. It almost halved the running time, meaning that the multi-threading worked.

Comment: @TheCompWiz That is absolutely wrong! Reasons are too numerous to list here, but for start garbage collector always has its own thread!

Answer (score 3):

The advantage is subtle at best.  Basically it means that your web browser can process very large integer values more efficiently and without conversion.  There's quite a bit of number-crunching that goes on behind the scenes of the web browser.  Unfortunately, to the average user... it means nothing.  Any improvements you see will be minimal at best.

Comment: Are there any benchmarks comparing a 64-bit browser running normally versus it running in 32-bit compatibility mode on Mac? (Right click dock icon > get info > check the 32-bit mode box). And let's talk about benchmarks on normal websites, not synthetic programs that purposely do bitwise manipulation.